# how to add value to a particular column and row in a gridView in javascript?

Tags: javascript, gridview

I am trying to add a value to a gridView column on a specific row via Javascript. Previously I have done this via .NET.

But now I want to try this alternative:-

```
document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%%>').rows[1].cells[1].value = IDentification#;
```

This is obviously not the correct syntax. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `innerHTML`  not `value`

```
document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>')
 .rows[1]
 .cells[1]
 .innerHTML= yourvariable; //or "astring"
```

This will insert the text in your variable to 2nd row's 2nd column of the table rendered by the gridview.

Comment: I get the error unable to value of property 'rows' ..null or undefined .... my string does have value tho...

Comment: it probably means `document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>')` is null. See view source and check what is the id of the table rendered.

Comment: "Unable to get value of the property 'rows': object is null or undefined"

How do I set the value not to null ?

Comment: It is because your id is wrong or you are executing the script before the gridview has rendered completely. What does page view source when you inspect the html table rendered by the grid view?

Comment: ok so I commented out the code that crashes my page, and view sourced it, looks like my gridview table id is not here at all.....

Comment: aah that is the problem :) Are you giving the CLientId, you can figure it out. But try this.. give a class name and do `document.getElementsByClassName('mygrid')[0].rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML ="somevalue"`

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'rows': object is null or undefined

       document.getElementsByClassName('GridView1')[0].rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = claim_no;

Comment: Give CssClass="GridView1" in the gridview and try.. You have id but not sure why it is not getting the clientId...

Comment: In view page source do you see the class?

Comment: i commented out the document.getElementsbyclassname... because that crashes my page and I viewed the page source.  this is what i got...

http://pastie.org/7918103

Comment: In your page source there is no grid view

Comment: i know!! how weird is that. is it because, it never gets called ? javascript is not my forte.

Comment: Just add this check so that it doesn't crash with js error `if(document.getElementsByClassName('GridView1').length != 0)
      document.getElementsByClassName('GridView1')[0].rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML = XXX;` You would need to figure out why grid is not getting rendered...

Comment: I see other controld getting rendered in your viewsource but no table generated by the gridview is there...

Comment: thanks dude. still no gridview tho... I just basically dragged and dropped the grid from the toolbox onto my aspx page design mode, edited columns. and thats it.

Comment: oh ok... Once you get it resolved this will work. revert back to getElementsById itself in that case(My original answer).. All the best...

Comment: my gridview is empty tho.. i adding the first element at [0].[0] location.

Comment: why do u think its not being generated?

Comment: I did not see it in the page source... Is it appearing now?

Comment: so adding the <td><tr> works from my client side. but adding GridView doesn't work from my client side. That led me to thinking, is GridView only server side??

Comment: Infact gridview gets rendered as html tables on the client side. do you see the grid on the page? if so check the view source using chrome dev toolbar.

Comment: I see the gridview tag on the aspx page. but as soon as i run my page, there are no gridview elements. weirdest thing. 

Gridview tag does say 'runat = server'